# AngularFire query denormalised data

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

i'm having some problem querying my data with firebase.

I have the below structure
[image]

The user has some pets and i want to get a list of all pets the user has in the pets node.
I did the following approach:

```
for (let petUID in this.user.pets) {
   this.af.database.object("/pets/" + petUID ).subscribe(data => {
      this.ownPets.push(data);
   });
}
```

At the end i get all the pets in my `ownPets` variable.
But it just like awkward to me this approach.

If any data is updated in the pets node from a pet that is inside the `ownPets` array, this pet is pushed again and i get the outdated and the new pet inside the `ownPets`.

I tried another approach: use the query method and send an array of objects in the `equalTo` but i get an error saying i can't send an array of objects.

```
this.af.database.list('/pets', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: "name",
      equalTo: ["pet1", "pet2"]
    }
  }).subscribe (data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Anyone have a better approach i can use?
Thanks

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but why don't you just create a temp array and push the new data into that and then simply `this.ownPets = newData`?